# React Native how to set state on a property(qtyCount) of object in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Thanks fo having a look!
I have an application where I need to increment & decrement multiple counters independently

```
state = {
windowCounters: [
{
  id: 0,
  image: singlePane125x125,
  type: 'Single Pane',
  unitPrice: 4.25,
  qtyCount: 0,
  subtotal: 0,
},
{
  id: 1,
  image: twoPane125x125,
  type: '2 Panes',
  unitPrice: 8.0,
  qtyCount: 0,
  subtotal: 0,
},
```

],
  };

I am struggling with my increment method, this is  1 of the ways I have 
 tried
 It only updates once

```
incrementCount = (id) => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  windowCounters: prevState.windowCounters.map(
    counter => (counter.id === id ? Object.assign(counter, { qtyCount: +1 }) : counter),
  ),
}));
```

};

Comment: What do you mean by `It only updates once`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like you are missing    `counter.qtyCount` in the increment statement.

Thats why its update only once as you are not incrementing instead just assigning `+1` value.

`{ qtyCount: +1 }`  //will not increment.

It should be.

```
counter => (counter.id === id ? 
              Object.assign(counter, { qtyCount: counter.qtyCount+1 }) : counter), 
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks that's all it was maybe I need to take a break!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `qtyCount: +1`, you are actually assigning 1 to the key `qtyCount`. That's why you're having the impression that the value is being updated just once (try to substitute it to +1000, and you'll see it more clear). What you have to do is add to the previous state value. Something like:

```
counter.qtyCount: counter.qtyCount +1
```

If you're having questions about it, you can live try this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help I see what you mean now

Comment: I don't mind you accepting the other answer, but can you at least upvote my answer for my effort? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Still learning how stack overflow works it meant a lot to me how you explained